# Concrete type is not assignable to generic type

Tags: typescript

```
type Id = <A>(a: A) => A

const id: Id = (a: number) => a;
```

If I use generics in this way the compiler will return an error saying

```
Type '(a: number) => number' is not assignable to type 'Id'.
  Types of parameters 'a' and 'a' are incompatible.
    Type 'A' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

I know it can be solved with 
`type Id<A> = (a: A) => A`
But what if I can't declare A at every point. Is there a way to just have it flow through, or be inferred?

Comment: If you remove the type annotation from the id const it should be assignable to types of Id<number>

Comment: @Michael that's correct. But as soon as I want to do something with `a` the compiler starts complaining:
`const id: Id = (a) => (a + 1);`
`Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'A' and '1'.`

Comment: @Michael is telling you (@bbz) that you should just write `const id = (a: number) => (a + 1);`.  You don't need a type annotation on `id` at all.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're experiencing is the difference between these two type definitions.

```
type Func1<A> = (a: A) =>  A;

type Func2 = <A>(a: A) =>  A;
```

Any function of type `Func1<A>` must specify its type *at the time it is defined.*

```
const func1: Func1<number> = (a: number): number => a;

func1(10); // works
func1("x"); // fails - we already decided it is of type `number`
```

Anything of type `Func2` must not specify its type *until it is called.*

```
const func2: Func2 = <X>(a: X): X => a;

func2(10); // works
func2("x"); // works
```

Here is a [playground link that illustrates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20Func1%3CA%3E%20%3D%20(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20%20A%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Func2%20%3D%20%3CA%3E(a%3A%20A)%20%3D%3E%20%20A%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20func1%3A%20Func1%3Cnumber%3E%20%3D%20(a%3A%20number)%3A%20number%20%3D%3E%20a%3B%0D%0Afunc1(10)%3B%20%2F%2F%20works%0D%0Afunc1(%22x%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20fails%20-%20we%20already%20decided%20it%20is%20of%20type%20%60string%60%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20func2%3A%20Func2%20%3D%20%3CX%3E(a%3A%20X)%3A%20X%20%3D%3E%20a%3B%0D%0Afunc2(10)%3B%20%2F%2F%20works%0D%0Afunc2(%22x%22)%3B%20%2F%2F%20works).

The problem you were experiencing happened because you tried to specify the type of the function when you defined it instead of when you called it.

Comment: Thanks Shaun. Like I mentioned I'm aware of the difference. But your answer makes it a lot more clear!